# Why run-time created pictureBox is not appears?

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime, picturebox

I am trying to create pictureBox runtime and can't do this.

I am using this code:

```
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);

            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(109, 32);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width * 10, height * 10);
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 4;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = resizedImage;
            this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);

            this.pictureBox1.SetControlZIndex(999);
            this.groupBox1.SetControlZIndex(10);
            this.SetControlZIndex(1);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();

            this.Update();
```

Also, pictureBox is declared as Form1 field (this).

Code works without any errors (try catch doesn't catch anything).

I see nothing on 109, 32 position.

I also assumed that it is z-index problem (as in html mb...) and find how to manage controls z-index, but it didn't helped me.

How I can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing there.  If you want it to be in front, then just use BringToFront():

```
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(109, 32);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(width * 10, height * 10);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 4;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = resizedImage;
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox_Click);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.pictureBox1.BringToFront();
```

It works fine for me.  We're going to need more details about your app...